# Is .hash in Objective-C equivalent to .hashValue in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash

Is `.hash` in Objective-C equivalent to `.hashValue` in Swift ?

If not, what is the equivalent of `.hashValue` in Objective-C ?

This relates to an issue I have here ( I am converting a Swift Library into Objective-C as an exercise) :

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) formatter : (NSDateFormatterStyle *) dateStyle : (NSDateFormatterStyle *) timeStyle : (BOOL) doesRelativeDateFormatting : (NSTimeZone *) timeZone : (NSLocale *) locale {
    timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@", dateStyle.hash, timeStyle.hash, doesRelativeDateFormatting.hash, timeZone.hash, locale.hash];
    NSMutableDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
    NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
    if (cachedDateFormatter != nil) {
        return cachedDateFormatter;
    }
    else {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        formatter.dateStyle = *(dateStyle);
        formatter.timeStyle = *(timeStyle);
        formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = doesRelativeDateFormatting;
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone;
        formatter.locale = locale;
        formatters[hashKey] = formatter;
        return formatter;
    }
}
```

Tells me on this line: `NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@", dateStyle.hash, timeStyle.hash, doesRelativeDateFormatting.hash, timeZone.hash, locale.hash];`

Member reference base type "NSDateFormatterStyle *" (aka "enum NSDateFormatterStyle*") is not a structure or union

Original Swift code:

```
private class func formatter(dateStyle dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle, doesRelativeDateFormatting: Bool, timeZone: NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone(), locale: NSLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()) -> NSDateFormatter {
        var formatters = NSDate.sharedDateFormatters()
        let hashKey = "\(dateStyle.hashValue)\(timeStyle.hashValue)\(doesRelativeDateFormatting.hashValue)\(timeZone.hashValue)\(locale.hashValue)"
        if let cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey] {
            return cachedDateFormatter
        } else {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = dateStyle
            formatter.timeStyle = timeStyle
            formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = doesRelativeDateFormatting
            formatter.timeZone = timeZone
            formatter.locale = locale
            formatters[hashKey] = formatter
            return formatter
        }
    }
```

Comment: `hash` is from `NSObject`. You can't call `hash` on primitive types.

Comment: And `NSDateFormatterStyle` is an enum. You shouldn't be passing it as a pointer.

Comment: And a hash isn't unique. You seem to want to create a unique key based on hash values. That's not appropriate.

Comment: I am converting a Swift library into Objective-C. This is the way I converted it into Objective-C Syntax. Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. `NSDateFormatterStyle` is an enum. You should not use pointers for these parameters.
2. `hash` is only available through `NSObject`. Therefore you can't call `hash` on primitive types in Objective-C.
3. `hash` returns `NSUInteger` but your `stringWithFormat` is using the `%@` specifier. That won't work. `%@` is only for object pointers.
4. Your use of anonymous parameters in the method name is non-standard.

Your code needs to be something like this:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)formatter:(NSDateFormatterStyle)dateStyle timeStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)timeStyle relativeDateFormatting:(BOOL)doesRelativeDateFormatting timeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone locale:(NSLocale *)locale {
    NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%lu%lu%lu%lu", (unsigned long)dateStyle, (unsigned long)timeStyle, (unsigned long)doesRelativeDateFormatting, (unsigned long)timeZone.hash, (unsigned long)locale.hash];
    NSMutableDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
    NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
    if (cachedDateFormatter != nil) {
        return cachedDateFormatter;
    }
    else {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        formatter.dateStyle = dateStyle;
        formatter.timeStyle = timeStyle;
        formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = doesRelativeDateFormatting;
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone;
        formatter.locale = locale;
        formatters[hashKey] = formatter;
        return formatter;
    }
}
```

With regard to the `hash` vs `hashValue` question. They are sort of the same thing. Though Swift provides the `hashValue` through the `Hashable` protocol and it is supported through all of Swift's built-in types like `Int` and `String`, etc.

`hash` is a method from `NSObject`. It can be used in Objective-C or Swift but only on classes that extend `NSObject`. It can't be used with primitive types.